# Beginner help: How I got the Geany terminal to work on Windows 10 (not a question, but probably useful to someone)

Tags: python, terminal, geany

So yeah, this isn't a question as such. Apologies if Stack has a better place for this kind of post. I just figured I might save some people a bit of future head scratching.

I was running Windows 10. Installed Geany with the standard 'geany-1.36_setup.exe' file for windows.

Opened a new file, 'test.py'. Typed in:

```html
print('test')
```

(It's no 'hello world', but hey, I fancied a change.)

And I got the dreaded 'cannot execute' error:

```html
09:05:16: Cannot execute build command "-e /bin/sh "C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\libexec\geany\geany-run-helper" "C:\Users\donenmax\Desktop\python" 0 python "test.py"": The system cannot find the file specified. Check the Terminal setting in Preferences
```

So I did what any beginner would do: I googled.

Naturally, I started off searching for what to put in the Terminal Setting of preferences. Everyone seemed to have a different answer. What doesn't help is that: 
1)A lot of people don't use the default terminal for various reasons, so their guidance won't work without a lot of mods. (To be fair, the default terminal ain't the best for certain work). 
2)The default terminal setting, 'x-term-emulator' appears, from what my little brain can figure out, to be a linux command. Maybe other people have got it to work on Windows, I dunno. But the closest answers I got to changing this to something Windows could understand were along the lines of 'oh, you'll need cmd.exe, but I've no idea what switches you will need.'

Sorry, beginner here...what the heck is a switch? 
Well, it turns out that the '-e /bin/sh' entry that follows the 'x-term-emulator' text is, guess what, a linux command (or not something Windows understands, anyhow.)

Note: the '%c' command that follows 'sh' should not be removed, as this is substituted with the run script name. Basically, %c tells Geany what script to execute.

So then, going into 'Preferences' and accessing the 'Terminal' setting, I replaced

```html
x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/sh %c
```

with

```html
cmd.exe /Q /C %c
```

That got me as far as a blank terminal. Wooo! So, how to actually get anything to be executed?

More googling.

You have to go into the 'Build' tab, then select 'Set Build Commands'.

You will (or should) find something like:

```html
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
```

```html
python "%f"
```

You'll need to replace 'python' with wherever python.exe is stored on your machine. Just type 'python.exe' into the Windows search bar, then right click 'open file location'.

In my case, I replaced 'python "%f" with:

```html
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python
```

Boom! My terminal now works fine.

Apologies for making this a rather long post, but this was the result of about an hour's brow furrowing that is most likely shared with beginners in similar situations. Hopefully this will help some of you windows users out there. A lot of programming guidance I've come across seems to assume pretty hefty background knowledge :)

Comment: Thank you for your time helping others. I would suggest to ask your questions in the question section and answer yourself in the answer section. Let's follow the standard.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a tutorial / how-to.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks, and apologies. Where should tutorials be placed? The Stack Overflow landing page only seems to show questions.

Comment: SO/SE not made for tutorials / how-tos, there's no section for it. Maybe use Medium or something similar?

Comment: @Austin Thanks for your guidance. I did some fairly thorough searching earlier and couldn't find an 'answers' section. Are you referring to the meta.stackexchange site? Or, by 'answers', do you mean 'only answer someone else's question'?

Comment: Did you take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) ?

Comment: Your question is a perfectly fine answer. You can ask the question and also answer it yourself, but the answer should not be in the question. Else it's a tutorial / how-to.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks, will do in future.

Comment: You can do it now if you want to. But do it on superuser.com, as it won't be programming-related.

Comment: @Austin yes, but the tour appears, understandably, focused on how to ask appropriate questions and answer them in a useful way. So I wasn't sure where to place this. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @DanielF On the contrary, the Stack Overflow tour specifically states you can ask about "Software development tools".

Comment: @yamax87 did you get a different cmd window when you ran your command, or did it work in the Geany integrated terminal itself? Geany has an integrated terminal too that works on Linux at least